# How to remove purple header from the android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am strugling with removing this purple header from the android app. Tried following 2 solution, but none of them worked for me.

1. Change the style -> parent in style.xml

`<style name="Theme.MaxCogito" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

2. Adding following code to onCreate() (this code actually broke my code) [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOWW95u15S0)

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That "Purple bar" is called as the status bar. If you would like to hide it,

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
</application>
```

For `API_LEVEL < 16`

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
);
```

For `API_Level >= 16`

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getActionBar().hide();
```

Your code doesn't works because you API Level is newer than 16 (probably)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code inside `MainActivity` under the `onCreate` method:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

This requests the OS to change the visibility of the status bar to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method just add this
In Kotlin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

In Java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use that inside the styles of theme you are using.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="m_ammar_tentwenty" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_light_gray</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/app_white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/app_white</item>

        <!-- Status bar = responsible for the background color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Status bar text colors handle from here -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->


    </style>
</resources>
```